# No module named titlecase (existence confirmed)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, title-case

I tried to use the package called "titlecase" (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/titlecase)
My code works on jupyter notebook but it does not work when I tried to run it in cmd.

### Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function 

import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()

from titlecase import titlecase
f=open(r'C:\Users\GX\everyFirstLetterCapitalized.txt')
f.seek(0)
message = f.read()
outPut=titlecase(message)

f=open(r'C:\Users\GX\everyFirstLetterCapitalizedOutput.txt', 'w')
f.write("new output:-- {a}\n".format(a=now)+outPut)
f.close()
```

---

But, I always got the result:
ImportError: No module named titlecase

### I tried to use the following code to find the package, it does exist:

```
import imp
imp.find_module('titlecase')
```

---

Comment: How was `titlecase` installed?  Can you do `import pip` and `pip.main(['install', 'titlecase'])`?

Comment: *"My code works on jupyter notebook but it does not work when I tried to run it in cmd"*: this indicates that the code is ran in different environments, i.e. different Python versions or installations.

Answer (score 0):

1 of 2 things:
Do you have more than one installations  of python. If so never just use `pip`. use `pip<pythonversion>` for example `pip3 install etc`. if you have 2 versions of python 3.x or 2.x, then do `pip3.x install ...` (or 2.x)
2 of 2 things, Whats your path? system and python paths are needed to solve module import issues, otherwise we can't help you.

Try reinstalling using the method in section 1.